# IIS7 Permission Denied - ASP File Write

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

Unfortunately I don't have a whole lot of information on this.
I have a customer who has moved their site from an ancient system to IIS7 on Windows 2008 Server. Info about the error is below:

Error:
  E:\wwwroot\sp\xxx\online_data.xls 
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046'

Permission denied

/xxx/oat/exceldata.asp, line 52

Code:

```
49 response.write(server.mappath("online_data.xls")) 
50   
51 set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject") 
52 Set act = fso.CreateTextFile(server.mappath("online_data.xls"), true)
```

The only suggestion so far is to:

> grant the application pool
>   (DefaultAppPool / Classic AppPool)’s
>   impersonated identity read and write
>   permission to the physical folder
>   which the asp page reside

Will look at this when I get access, but other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that suggestion will work, another option is checking if the default app pool is running as Network Service and giving Network Service access to write to that folder

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. Still no action on site, but will follow up when I return.

Answer (score 12):

The provided answer is correct, but I needed a little more detail on how to accomplish it.  To make it really easy, follow the steps below. I was setting up an asp page counter on a sandbox system in our intranet.

1. Open Computer Management.
2. Drill down to the IIS server
   Management
3. In the Connections pane, click on
   Application Pools
4. In the Application Pools pane,
   right-click on DefaultAppPool and
   choose Advanced Settings. Look in
   the Process Model section.
5. By default, the Identity property is
   set to ApplicationPoolIdentity. 
   This is a built-in account.
6. If it's set to the default, then you
   can use the built-in user
   machinename\IUSR for your
   permissions settings.  I had to
   specify the machine name because
   this is a virtualized server, YMMV.
7. If it's not set to the default, use
   that username for your permissions
   settings.
8. Cancel out of the dialog and return
   to Windows Explorer, to the folder
   where you need to add permission.
9. Right-click to get Permission
   settings.
10. Set up machinename\IUSR or the
     non-default username you determined
     in steps 6/7 above. Grant
     permissions as needed.

This helped:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/140/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis-7/

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion is correct. If the path to the solution is not immediately obvious for whatever configuration reasons, try running procmon (filter on "online_data.xls") and see who's failing, why, and what user account they run under. Then check the ACLs.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem in Windows 7 and my solution was changing the Authentication. From IIS, select the site, go to Authentication, disable Anonymous Authentication and enable Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Spent a bit of time with something similar.  Even with the correct settings it wasn't working.

I then tried create the actual file first on the server.  Turned out to be the trick that worked.  Now my ASP page writes to the existing file no problem.

Must be something about creating a new doc from scratch that is another issue.