# FileSystemObject with Classic ASP does not working good on IIS7+ Win server 2008

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, windows-server-2008, filesystemobject

Recently i move my classic asp application from Windows XP + IIS5 to Windows Server 2008 + IIS7.
It is almost everything working fine except one thing... the FileSystemObject doesn't reach files or folders on shared folder in remote PC.
The following code always results with "File Doesn't Exists" and believe me the file exist!!

```
set fg=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if fg.FileExists("\\netapp1\CM\CompilationResults\6.6 Release\TCL\L6.50.001\alias.tcl") then
     response.write("File Exists")
else
     response.write("File Doesn't Exists")
end if
```

When trying the FileExists on local folder it works OK. This is working fine:

```
if fg.FileExists(Server.MapPath ("Logs\Add pc\Status log\status_file.txt")) then ......
```

**Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?**

Comment: Does the user you're running on have access to the file & its network share on the remote PC?

Comment: The Remote PC has read permissions to... "Authenticated Users" "Domain Users" and some private users.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a issue related to permissions you have on inetpub folder,

check this for hints

http://forums.iis.net/t/1149760.aspx

http://forums.iis.net/t/1154590.aspx

[IIS7 Permission Denied - ASP File Write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505634/iis7-permission-denied-asp-file-write)

http://forums.iis.net/t/1182149.aspx