# ASP.NET IIS File create permission while using Thread

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, filestream

I am trying to create a file in my ASP.NET application (IIS 7.5). The file write is done in a separate thread and is giving access not available error.

What kind of permission does the directory need? I have tried giving full access to IIS_IUSRS and IUSR. But this did not work. Everything works okay in my local machine, but once deployed on the server, I get access error.

```
string filePath = MapPath("c:\FilePath\");

PrintFile printFile = new PrintFile();
Thread printFileThread = new Thread(delegate()
                {
                    printFile.PrintFile(filePath);
                });

printFileThread.Start();


public void PrintFile(string filePath)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(filePath) == false)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
            }

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath + "NewFile.pdf", FileMode.Create);
        }
```

Comment: I believe this post addressed your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505634/iis7-permission-denied-asp-file-write

Comment: sorry, this did not work. I have give full access to IUSR on the directory. Tried IIS_IUSRS also.

The issue is happening while I create directory/file in a separate thread. The main thread can create directory/file just fine.

Comment: Can you post your code and the exact error name or trace?

Comment: I have updated the original post with code. The error is that "You do not have access to this folder".

Comment: Just to clear up a suspicion I have: You are not trying to write to the computer of the user, are you? I have seen that a few times.

Comment: No, the file is to be saved in the web server.

If I execute the PrintFile(string filePath) method in the main thread, the file gets created just fine.

Comment: Note, that you cannot really do background work in ASP.NET anyway (http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/). So this whole question might be moot. You probably shouldn't run this code on a thread anyway.

Comment: My code is fine and it is working fine. 

The issue was that, I had referenced System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session and this was blowing up. System.Web.HttpContext.Current is null in the new thread, but not in the main thread. Thanks rommik and usr for your replies.